# System_Daemon and pcntl on centos with php 5.4.9

Tags: php, fork, daemon, pcntl

I've been using System_Daemon class to create a daemon to send sms.

The script worked perfect with php 5.3.8, but now, with php 5.4.9 it crashes but no error or notice messages is created.

In the function _fork, of System_Daemon class, always return a value that tells it's parent

```
static protected function _fork()
{
    self::debug('forking {appName} daemon');
    $pid = pcntl_fork();

    if ($pid === -1) {
        // Error
        return self::warning('Process could not be forked');
    } else if ($pid) {
        // Parent
        self::debug('Ending {appName} parent process');
        // Die without attracting attention
        exit();
    } else {
        // Child
        self::$_processIsChild = true;
        self::$_isDying        = false;
        self::$_processId      = posix_getpid();
        return true;
    }
}
```

So, in _summon() function, where it ask about _fork() returned value, always is equal to false.

I've red this post, from another member who has a similar issue:
[PHP Pear system_daemon doesn't fork](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11871500/php-pear-system-daemon-doesnt-fork)

I've made his suggestions but with no success.

Can somebody, please, give me a hand with this?

I'm so sorry about my english, i made an effort to explain myself.